# How to get the id from the url then insert it into the data base using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

Hopefully all this info helps out.

So what I am doing is i have a forum page that I have set up to were you can select a category, from that category you can insert a post into that category.  What I need help with is getting the id of that category for the database so that post will show up when I echo it out. In other words linking ids to the pages upon insert.

ok so i know that its inserting the username message title ect but what its not doing is getting the 1 from the url and inserting that 1 into the database under category_id

Here is my url  I left out the main http to shorten this up but the rest of it were the number 1 is what I am wanting to get and insert cause that its going to change depending on the category you choose. `index.php/forum/create_post/1`

This is what my category table has

```
ID    title   

1     community
```

This is what my post table has were all the main info comes from and were I am wanting to connect the category_id to the main category table.

**id**,  **title** message date user id category_id flaged username

This is the first view that will insert the new post

View:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="module">
        <?php echo form_open('forum/create_post'); ?>
        <div>
            <?php
            echo form_label('Title', 'title');
            echo form_input('title', '');
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <?php
            echo form_label('Message', 'message');
            echo form_input('message', '');
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <?php echo form_submit('create', 'create new post'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Controller: here is the section in the controller were I am passing all my input if no to

```
 public function create_post() {
    if( !$this->session->userdata('username') ) {
        redirect('/'); // please login to continue
    }

    if( $this->input->post('create') ) {


        $this->forum->createpost(array(
          // $id= $this->uri->segment(3),
           'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
           'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
           'user_id'=> $this->session->userdata('id'),
           'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username'),

         ));

    }

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('forum/create_post');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Here is the model that i'am inserting the data to

```
public function createpost($data){
 $this->db->insert('post',$data);


}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the main category id to create page and store in db as parent category?

Comment: to the get  url paramter 1 use $id= $this->uri->segment(3);

Comment: ok i have done that before it retrieves in but how do i make it insert into the data base?

Comment: kinda i think if iam under standing you right? what iam trying t0 do is taking that main id from the category and inserting it into the category_id inorder to link to the category that its in. this way when its gets echoed out it will only echo out in that category

Answer (score 2):

As per your URL `index.php/forum/create_post/1`, You controller function should be as below to meet CI Standard.

```
public function create_post($category_id) {
```

So you can access `$category_id` directly. No need to get url segment.

```
   $res =  $this->forum->createpost(array(
        $id= $category_id,
       'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
       'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
       'user_id'=> $this->session->userdata('id'),
       'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username'),

     ));
if($res)
{
 // show thanks msg
}
else
{
 // show error msg
}
```

In your model:

You can check that data is inserted

```
public function createpost($data)
{     
   $this->db->insert('post',$data);
   if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
     return true;
   else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: so once i do that how to make sure its inputing into the data base is were iam blanking at?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Do you want to make sure data is inserted or not?

Comment: yea i want to take all that data aloing with the id of the page that its on wich will be the category that its being inserted into and insert the id along with evrey thing else into the data base

Comment: hope fully that makes more sense if not let me know

Comment: ok so i know that its inserting the username message title ect but what its not doing is getting the 1 from the url and inserting that 1 into the database under category_id

Comment: Are you passing $category_id to `create_post()`

Comment: thats what iam trying to find out yes casue in the data base there is category_id so iam trying to get that 1 from the url to insert int into that as i said above if need be let me know what else you would need or if there is a way i could chat off here to better explain it to you

Comment: if need be add me on skype gwartney2 casue i know this is kinda confusing on what it is iam doing its just really hard to explain

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending /1 to the page again. Your form must send that /1 from original url.

```
<?php echo form_open('forum/create_post'); ?>
```

create_post method wont receive a 3rd segment, because it doesn't exists. Store category id in a input hidden and access it by $this->input->post('category_id'):

#### Controller

```
public function create_post() {
if( !$this->session->userdata('username') ) {
    redirect('/'); // please login to continue
}

if( $this->input->post('create') ) {
    $this->forum->createpost(array(
       'category_id' => $this->input->post('category_id'),
       'title'   => $this->input->post('title'),
       'message' => $this->input->post('message'),
       'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
       'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username')
     ));
}

$data['category_id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('forum/create_post', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

#### View

```
    <div id="container">
    <div class="module">
        <?php echo form_open('forum/create_post'); ?>
        <div>
            <?php
            echo form_label('Title', 'title');
            echo form_input('title', '');
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <?php
            echo form_label('Message', 'message');
            echo form_input('message', '');
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <?php echo form_submit('create', 'create new post'); ?>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo $category_id; ?>">
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Also, ask yourself if there is a need to storage user ID and username. Isn't username attached to an ID? Couldn't it be retrieved by just selecting userID from a post?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what i needed to do make this all work i had to insert the uri segment into a hidden input forum to get it to insert into the right id box and now iam able to connect the right categorys